# What does grazing do?

Tags: danmaku-unlimited-2

While I was playing Danmaku Unlimited 2, I saw a counter, underneath the point multipler. It says grazed, and I saw it going up as I got very close to bullets, so I am assuming it counts number of bullets grazed. BUT, what does that mean, and why should I graze bullets?

[image]

Not me playing, just a good picture to represent what I am refering to.

Answer (score 2):

Grazing is the act of going very close to the bullet and having them "graze" your hit point. you'll hear a *tick* sound and your ship will spark when you graze successfully.

Grazing charges your trance gauge (right) faster to let you use your ultimate more often.

There is also an additional point bonus you receive after finishing the stage for grazing.

Comment: But what about the +(number) directly underneath it?

Comment: It's just a point bonus

Comment: Like it adds (number) each time a point is earned?